# How to restrict same user to assign in one group if the user is already assign using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent, relationship

This is my body request:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "group_members": [96,97]
}
```

Here id 1 is group id and group_members 96 and 97 is users id and I assigned users 96 and 97 with group id 1 and when I try to assign again the users with same id that is 96 and 97 it should not assigned it should show message that users is already assigned with with this group id

How can I achieve this? I have also shared code:

```
                    try{

        $request->request->add(['created_by' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $groupMembers = Group::where('id', $request->get('id'))->first();
        $groupMembers->users()->attach($request->get('group_members', []));


        DB::commit();

        return response([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'Group members added',
        ], 200);

    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        return response([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => __('messages.validation_errors'),
            'errors' => $ex->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
    }
```

Comment: There is no if statement to check if the group members are already attached to the user

Comment: can you show me with code using the if statement

Comment: @syed1234 How about if some of the users are added and some not ? i.e `96` has already assigned to group `1` but `97` not. How do you want to handle this case?

Comment: in this case message should not be display it should not add 96 but should add 97

Comment: and in case both are already assigned then there should be message display , can you please help me to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to use `syncWithoutDetaching` method which will automatically attach users that are not attached and ignore the ones that are already attached.

```
$groupMembers->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($request->get('group_members'));
```

However if you really need to show error message, the following should work:

```
$associatedUsers = $groupMembers->users()->whereIn('users.id', $request->get('group_members'))->pluck('users.id'); // It'll give all attached user IDs

if(!$unAssociatedUserIds = array_diff($request->get('group_members'), $associatedUsers)) {
            // throw error message
           // return response
        }
$groupMembers->users()->attach($unAssociatedUserIds);
```

It is recommended to validate your data first.

Hope it helps!

Comment: can you please check there is error in $groupMembers->users()->('users.id', $request->get('group_members'))->pluck('users.id');   // ('users.id')

Comment: @syed1234 I updated the answer. Please give it a try.